# OpenSuse Tumbleweed: Booting to TTY1 console (no GUI)

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, nvidia, opensuse

After running updates or installations with Zypper, I sometimes reboot to find myself stuck in a console (tty1). The first time, it was directly after I installed VirtualBox. That time, I managed to find a temporary solution by running a `sudo zypper dup`. The other two times, it happened after running `sudo zypper dup`, just to update the system. Both of those times I had to rollback using snapper.

Unfortunately, following other posts describing similar issues have not lead to any success. I have tried `ctrl + alt + f7`, which seems to do nothing on my system. I also checked to ensure the display manager was running, which it was.

Looking at my /var/log/Xorg.0.log.old file, there is one section of errors (that I don't understand):

```
[   185.150] (EE) NVIDIA: Failed to initialize the NVIDIA kernel module. Please see the
 134   │ [   185.150] (EE) NVIDIA:     system's kernel log for additional error messages and
 135   │ [   185.150] (EE) NVIDIA:     consult the NVIDIA README for details.
 136   │ [   185.633] (EE) [drm] Failed to open DRM device for pci:0000:2d:00.0: -19
 137   │ [   185.633] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
 138   │ [   185.633] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
 139   │ [   185.633] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
```

Looking at the log directory now, I don't see any kernel log files, and the boot.log file has no timestamps that date back to the issue.

I do think it's interesting that the issue references a kernel module. Each time this issue occurred, I always see the same message in the terminal: `Kernel 6.5.2-1-default (tty1)`. After rolling back with snapper, the system kernel is listed as: `6.4.12-1-default`. I don't know if that's actually of any value here, but I found it interesting.

If anyone has any suggestions or clues as to why this is occurring, thank you ahead of time!

Here are some specs if they are of any use:

```
CPU:
  Info: 8-core model: AMD Ryzen 7 3700X bits: 64 type: MT MCP arch: Zen 2
    rev: 0 cache: L1: 512 KiB L2: 4 MiB L3: 32 MiB
  Speed (MHz): avg: 2323 high: 3600 min/max: 2200/4426 boost: enabled cores:
    1: 2200 2: 2200 3: 2200 4: 2772 5: 2200 6: 2200 7: 2200 8: 2200 9: 2200
    10: 2200 11: 2200 12: 2200 13: 3600 14: 2200 15: 2200 16: 2200
    bogomips: 115242
  Flags: avx avx2 ht lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 sse4a ssse3 svm
Graphics:
  Device-1: NVIDIA TU104 [GeForce RTX 2070 SUPER] vendor: eVga.com.
    driver: nvidia v: 470.199.02 arch: Turing bus-ID: 2d:00.0
  Display: x11 server: X.org v: 1.21.1.8 driver: X: loaded: nvidia
    unloaded: fbdev,modesetting,nouveau,vesa gpu: nvidia,nvidia-nvswitch
    resolution: 1: 2560x1440 2: 2560x1440~60Hz
  API: OpenGL v: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 470.199.02 renderer: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2070
    SUPER/PCIe/SSE2 direct-render: Yes
```